# Is possible to simplify this expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

After I run this code:

```
8/Sum[(20 m + 3) (-1)^m (4 m)!/((4 Sqrt[2])^(4 m) (m!)^4), {m, 0, Infinity}]
```

> 256/(3 (32 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/4, 1/2, 3/4}, {1, 1}, -(1/4)] -
> 5 HypergeometricPFQ[{5/4, 3/2, 7/4}, {2, 2}, -(1/4)]))

But as I know, the final result is $\pi$. Is possible to simplify this result to $\pi$? As I try, the `FullSimplify` don't work totally and `FunctionExpand` will just get a expression about `EllipticK`...

Comment: I find the required simplification as art for art's sake. What is $\pi$? This real irrational number is in fact the sum of a certain series or the limit of a certain sequence.

Comment: `PossibleZeroQ[% - π]` returns `True`.

Comment: @user64494 So you think it is impossible to ask mma to simplify this expression?

Comment: No, I don't think so. However, I don't see much sense in that simplification as I wrote in my above comment.

Comment: @Roman First time to meet this function. But why `PossibleZeroQ[Log[a b] - Log[a] - Log[b]]` is not `True`?

Comment: Try substituting `-1` for `a` and `b` in your `Log` formula.

Comment: @yode Since `Log[x]` is a multi-value function when `x` is not a positive number.

Comment: @cvgmt `PossibleZeroQ[Log[a b] - Log[a] - Log[b], Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0]`  return `False` still

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[expr];
expr=8/Sum[(20 m + 3) (-1)^m (4 m)!/((4 Sqrt[2])^(4 m) (m!)^4), {m, 0, Infinity}];
Reduce[expr == π]
```

> `True`

Comment: I get a warning that `Reduce` is assuming the equation is `True`. It seems worth mentioning to me

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't know why when  we run other command and then run above code,then there are no warning message.

Comment: The result is cached. Try `ClearSystemCache[];` before rerunning `Reduce[]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Thanks!  `ClearSystemCache`  is new to me.